# Angular 2 refresh component from others using service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to ask about refreshing component in Angular 4.

I have this structure for my page:

Product Component

- Product Filter Component
- Product List Component

What I want is to connect Product Filter and Product List, so if user change his preferred filter, product list data will change.

I have searched and looks like creating a service will be a solution, but I'm not sure how to create this and how service works. (I still learn how Angular 2 / 4 works, and this is my first JavaScript framework).

Comment: Check out https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks, i have read it and looks like my problem is almost same with countdown example. Except on countdown example, its Parent - Child Interaction and mine is Child - Child Interaction. can i apply this to my problem?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some code. If you want to use a service, there is also [a section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) on how you can do this. For further help, please post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new service for subscribing event from `ProductFilterComponent`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EventSubscribeService {

  private eventSubject: Subject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor() { }

// set observable of this subject
  get $getEventSubject(): Observable<any> {
    return this.eventSubject.asObservable();
  }
// remove from observer
  resetEventObserver(): void {
    this.eventSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
  }
// send event to observers
  sendCustomEvent():void {
    this.eventSubject.next(true);
  }

}
```

Then define this service as `provider` of Module which contains `ProductCompont` and its child components.

```
@NgModule({
...
providers: [
    ...
    EventSubscribeService
    ...
  ],
...
```

Next is straight forward. (* Please don't forget to define instance of service in constructor. I am mentioning this because you are learning Angular. I hope you 'v already know how to use service. sorry. :) ).

`FilterChangeEvent` of `ProductFilterComponent` could be like this.

EDIT : **Template of ProductFilterComponent**

```
...
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="onFilterChangeEvent($event)">ChangeFilterButton<button>
...
```

UPDATE : **ButtonClickEvent could be handled as below**

```
onFilterChangeEvent(param:any):void {
    this.serviceInstance.sendCustomEvent();
  }
```

Last thing is getting subscribed event in `ProductListComponent`.

```
 constructor(
      private serviceInstance: EventSubscribeService,
  ) {
    this.serviceInstance.$getEventSubject.subscribe(event => {
      // here you can do anything what you are going to do
    });
  }


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.serviceInstance.resetEventObserver();
  }
```

Comment: for this statement "FilterChangeEvent of ProductListComponent could be like this."  are you sure this for ProductListComponent  and not ProductFilterComponent ? because i don't find any code for ProductFilterComponent

Comment: Yes, sorry, for my misspelling. `FilterChangeEvent()` is the event of **ProductFilterComponent**. I edited answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your update !! if i'm not wrong, all things that i want to ProductListComponent do after ProductFilterComponent trigger an event ( like refreshing data, etc) are going in into subscribe event on constructor, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Service is Subject and ProductListComponent is Observer of Subject. And ProductFilterComponent is the 3rd one which makes events on Subject.

Comment: Hi thanks for your explanations :) i still a bit confuse with how ProductFilterComponent send it filter component to service side, because on your code, sendCustomEvent() is no need params and also  this.eventSubject.next(true) so onFilterChangeEvent(param:any) looked not send any params

Comment: Actually if you want to send any parameter to function then you can add parameter to Subject. For example if you want send current state of ProductFilterComponent then you can send it through parameter. also if you need to set various states ,just send it through param and observer will check param and check state. This is oriented from Communication between components in Angular2(2 way - EventEmitter and Observer).

Comment: Thanks !! it works on my application !! But i have to separate event related services from other services and i use BehaviorSubject instead of ReplaySubject